# How to read a COLT or other paper related learning theory?

Tags: lg.learning, advice-request

I am a master student right now. And first time met the theoretical computer science, I am really interested in it, and especially the learning theory part. Wish to do research about this part in the future.

After read(actually can not understand) the paper from COLT, which known as the top conference in learning theory, I am stuck in the mathematical part. I really want to know how to prepare for the learning theory, is there some lecture notes,books or course videos I can read or watch? Or some lab and professors you would recommend for me?

It would be very helpful to a master student. Thank you in advance.

Comment: books: (1) understanding machine learning (2) foundations of machine learning

Comment: Can you be specific about the topic(s) of the paper? What techniques are involved? Do you at least understand the *statement* of the results?